# Использование существительного во множественном или единственном числе

Tags: выбор-слов

В здании есть 3 этажа, на **каждом** из этих этажей есть **одна** кухня. Как правильно в таком случае сформулировать предложение:

На кухн**е** каждого этажа...

На кухн**ях** каждого этажа...

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На кухне каждого этажа.

"Каждый" означает "любой отдельно рассматриваемый", а рассматривая отдельно взятый этаж, можно говорить только об одной кухне. Иначе выходит в выражении "на кухнях всех этажей", где этажи рассматриваются все вместе. Ср. "в сердце каждого соотечественника" и "в сердцах всех соотечественников".

Answer (score 4):

... думаю, что на кухнЕ... на каждом этаже ведь ОДНА кухня...

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ***на кухне каждого этажа***. К сожалению, я не могу дать объяснение (а вы вроде как и не просили, собственно говоря). У Розенталя в книге «Говорите и пишите по-русски правильно» есть тема об этом.